# How to read a value of property from object using string in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting a object of multiple array in my angular app from my rest service.

based on property name, I want to access the the value from incoming object.

object is like

```
data{
array1:{},
array2:{},
array3:{}
}
```

the number of array can change and also their names. I have another array which has all these array names like...

```
arraynames = {array1,array2,array3}
```

I tried to retrieve the value like...

```
data[arraynames[0]]
or
data[0]
or 
data[array1]
```

but nothing seems working and they are returning undefined.

how can I retrieve the value of array from data.

Comment: Use `data.array1` to access property "array1".

Comment: `arraynames`, as provided, is not an array; its an object that is not defined correctly. If you have `arraynames = ['array1','array2','array3']`, then using `data[arraynames[0]]` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Object.values(data)[0];
//or
data.array1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export class AppComponent {
  data = {
    array1: {id:1},
    array2: {id:2},
    array3: {id:3}
  }

  arraynames =["array1", "array2","array3"]

  constructor() {
    this.arraynames.forEach(x => {
      console.log(this.data[x])
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array need to be string array like
arraynames = ['array1','array2','array3']. Now it  will work as data[arraynames[0]]